# How to send message/content in fb messenger to user never been in messenger?

Tags: bots

I have an FB app which is a bot app. It subscribes as a primary responder of a page.

I get a callback when any user comments/like in any post of the page through the user never been in the messenger. on the basis of this kind of comment and likes, BOT wants to send messages to the user from the page.

But I can't send messages to the user if the user has not been in messanger at least once.

Answer (score 0):

find this api : 
Private Replies allows Businesses to reply to Post Comments and Visitor Posts made on their Page with a single message on Messenger.

The message is sent just like any regular message using the Send API but referencing either the Page Post of comment that will be replied.

When using this feature, the user will get a reference with a link to the post or comment that is getting the reply.

Private replies to posts or comments are allowed within 7 days of the creation date of the user post or comment.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/private-replies